# EC2 disabling SSH password authentication from snapshot

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I maintain a CentOS 7 server in AWS EC2 which uses password authentication instead of private keys (this is beyond my control).

I recently started testing a daily backup system using snapshots of the EBS volume. However, if I create an AMI from those snapshots and launch a new instance, it is impossible to connect using SSH. I investigated further and found out that the reason is because at instance launch, EC2 changes my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` from `PasswordAuthentication yes` to `PasswordAuthentication no`. This happens even if I choose not to associate a key pair during the launch wizard.

Is there some way to prevent EC2 from doing this unwanted modification? Is this located in a script somewhere inside the machine that I can edit or disable?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working. These launch-time configurations (called `cloud_init`) are located inside `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`. Just change `ssh_pwauth` to 1 in the main machine and future snapshots will already work appropriately.